# Jquery add up values on click

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with adding up values when on click function is performed.

I have simple radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="product1" class="price" value="4" /> 4
<input type="radio" name="product2" class="price" value="6" /> 6
```

I would like to add up values when click is performed. Obviously I can get values on click but I don't know how to add them up.

```
$('.price').click(function() {
    price = $(this).val();
}
```

OK, other issue.

What if we have two separate click functions like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="product1" class="price" value="4" /> 4
<input type="radio" name="product2" class="price" value="6" /> 6

<input type="radio" name="product1" class="number" value="3" /> 3
<input type="radio" name="product2" class="number" value="7" /> 7
```

and

```
$('.price').click(function() {
    price = $(this).val();
}

$('.number').click(function() {
    number = $(this).val();
}
```

How to add up values from .price radio and .number radio?
On top of that make sure you can only add one value from each, not that it will be adding all values regardless of which group of radio buttons?

Comment: Why is this `radio` and not a `checkbox` (there are 2 different names, hence 2 independent `radios`)? Also, what do you want to add the values to and/or what kind of problem do you have with the addition (the .val() in question returns a string, you know...)?

Comment: I hope edit explains it better

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var price = 0;

$('.price').click(function() {
    price += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
}
```

Comment: That is a good answer.  I just want to point out that it will add a value every time you click a radio button, even if it was added before.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure you can only add once?

Comment: @Chriser How many such radio `.price` or `.number` do you have ? In your edit I just only one, if so what are you adding up?

Comment: @Vega There are about 6 groups of radio buttons with about 4-6 options. I would like to be able to click on one option from each group and value will be add up. If I will change selection, total will change as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the question in terms of elements employed to show/select prices, so I'll just add few hints with the hope that they will be useful:

To select all radio buttons of given name (e.g. "product1"), you do:

```
$('input:radio[name="product1"]')
```

To select all radio buttons of givan name, that are checked (there can be only one):

```
$('input:radio[name="product1"]:checked')
```

To select all checked radio buttons regardless of the name:

```
$('input:radio:checked')
```

Function to sum up all values (parse-able as numbers) in a jQuery collection of input elements:

```
function sumValues($inputs) {
    var sum = 0;
    $inputs.each(function () { sum += +this.value; });
    return sum;
};
```

Your handler then should look something like this (insert appropriate selector):

```
$(<whatever-triggers-recalc>).click(function() {
    // change selector to the one that selects the radios you need summed
    var sum = sumValues( $('input:radio[name="product1"]') );
    // here, you have your sum
});
```

You don't want to **update** the sum (on an event), instead you need to **recalculate** it every time.

You probably dont need `classes`, the `name` attribute should suffice if it is enough to identify the information that is to be sent to the server.

I hope these are helpful.